# Display a page without log in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a page that is supposed to be visible regardless of user log in.
I've tried using `$this->middleware('auth')->except('getStats')` but it didn't work.
I tried to pass url in `Handler.php` where it redirects unauthenticated users to login page, but it didn't work.
Any suggestion would be appreciated as I've tried a lot of things but couldn't make it work.

**Handler.php :**

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)  {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

**PlanningController.php (where I passed the `except`):**

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('getStats');
}
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
      // Teste si l'utilisateur est ok
      if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        // Redirige vers l'accueil
        return redirect('/');
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `route/web.php` file that there is no middleware applied to the route itself or it is not under a group which is using `auth` middleware.

If any of the above is correct then just create another controller for that task and copy that method and paste it new controller and see if it works.